# What coin is this?

Tags: hebrew, mysticism-kabbalah

It is a little over an inch diameter, thicker and heavier than any coin would be.  The lettering almost seems random....or maybe the middle word is a name?

Can someone help me identify this coin?

[image: Coin 1]
[image: Coin 2]

Initial speculation is that it is either Masonic or Kabbalistic....

Comment: Where did you find it? (That may help someone identify it.)

Comment: I'll second what @DoubleAA said; moreover, do you have any reason to think it's related to Jewish life or learning? Otherwise, it wouldn't seem [to be on-topic here](http://mi.yodeya.com/faq#questions). That said, welcome to the site! I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Please consider [registering](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login) your [account](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/1472), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Friend's grandfather had it and he recently passed; he lived in Northern California.

I posted it in Judaism because it is Hebrew lettering and figured I'd find the most proficient hebrew speakers here.  Which topic area would be better?

Comment: @msh210, Would it make sense to simply reformulate to "Is this a Jewish coin? It's got Hebrew on it. If so, what is it? ..."

Comment: @IsaacMoses I guess.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4543298#4543298 et seq.

Comment: @Aaron, I'd suggest trying a [numismatic identification forum](http://www.coincommunity.com/forum/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=124). If it turns out that the coin is Jewish in origin, maybe you can emend your question with some basic information and ask for answers providing Judaic context. If you initially want people here to tell you what the letters are, you might want to upload a better quality photo; not all of the letters in the second photo (obverse side?) are clear.

Comment: I'm Jewish so I know the letters just don't recognize the phrasing/words with no spacing. I'll try that forum, thanks!

Comment: @Aaron If you ever figure it out, please come back and post an answer to your own question to fill us in.

Comment: @msh210: Consider closing this question, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/

Comment: @DragonLord, this seems dissimilar to the questions discussed in that blog post. There, the asker has information about something and seeks a hard copy of it; here, the asker has a hard copy of something and seeks information about it.

Answer (score 10):

Receiving no answer here, this asker then [asked the same question on another forum](http://www.coincommunity.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=119079). Answers there link to older discussions on the same site, from which the following excerpts are informative:

> …it isn't a coin, it's an occultic/spiritualist/kabbalistic healing charm. The design of the star-side is taken from the "Keys of Solomon", a mediaeval Kabbalistic (Jewish-derived esoteric teachings) text. See [here](http://www.esotericarchives.com/solomon/ksol.htm#chap21) for an English version of the text, with a translation of what the inscriptions are supposed to read.

> The particular lettering around the star is a mystic/occult magic symbol derived from Kabbalistic traditions, called the "second pentacle of Mars".

> The reason even Hebrew scholars are having trouble reading the inscriptions on these objects is that the design is a copy of a copy of a copy; errors have crept into the transcriptions and it no longer says what the original pentacle says.

I can in no way vouch for the accuracy of these statements (or of the linked-to text) or for the claim that this has anything to do with *kabala*. Possibly relevant are [Wikipedia on "Key of Solomon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_of_Solomon) and ["מפתח שלמה" at HebrewBooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/38124).